# Is there a reason for explicitly stating the template type?

Tags: c++, templates

Consider a simple function template:

```
template <typename T>
void FunctionTemplate(T t){
}

void MyFunction(){
    int a;
    FunctionTemplate(a);
    FunctionTemplate<int>(a);
}
```

In the first call to (`FunctionTemplate(a)`), the compiler works out the type which raises the question, is there any reason for the existence of the second way of calling FunctionTemplate (`FunctionTemplate<int>(a)`) or any compelling reasons where we could not use the first method?

**Edit:** My terminology my be a little off, so please edit as required.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Occasionally you will *want* to specify the template argument, even if you don't have to. Let's say your function takes an argument of type `T` and you have an `int` but you want the function to take it as a `float`. Then you would need to explicitly say `FunctionTemplate<float>(my_int)`.

There are also plenty of cases where the template parameter cannot be deduced. Consider the following:

```
template <typename T>
T FunctionTemplate() {
  return T();
}
```

No matter how you call this, if you don't provide the template argument, the type of `T` cannot be automatically deduced. The simple reason in this case is that the calling site says nothing about what it expects the return type to be.

For the terminology: when you do not specify the template arguments, the template is implicitly instantiated; when you do specify the template arguments, the template is explicitly instantiated.

Comment: I would choose `FunctionTemplate((float)my_int)` for such simple single-argument function template. Tastes vary, though!

Answer (score 9):

Suppose you want to pass the function to another method as a parameter;

```
myAlgorithm( myFunction<int> );
```

Or suppose you want to guarantee a floating-point version of a function is used for speed;

```
myFunction<float>( 2.0 );
```

(forgetting to write `2.0f` isn't a problem now)

Comment: sftrabbit also raises a good case in his answer; when the return type depends on the template, but none of the parameters.

Answer (score 7):

A usage is forcing the compiler to use a specific version of template function:

```
template <typename T>
T func(T x, T y)
{
  // ...
}

int main()
{
  int x = 10;
  float y = 20;

  func(x, y); //ERROR no matching function for call to 'func(int&, float&)'

  func<float>(x, y); // OK, Uses float version of func
}
```